# Remainder of a summation divided by $2^{12}$

Tags: number-theory, contest-math

For a positive integer $n$, let $f(n)$ be equal to $n$ if there is an integer $x$ such that $x^2-n$ is divisible by $2^{12}$, and let $f(n)$ be $0$ otherwise. Determine the remainder when $$\sum_{n=0}^{2^{12}-1} f(n)$$ is divided by $2^{12}$.

Source: Caltech Harvey Mudd Tournament

Comment: Hint: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_residue#Prime_power_modulus

Answer (score 1):

Basically, all we need is the fact that the squares in $(\mathbb{Z}/2^k\mathbb{Z})^\times$, for $k\geq 3$, are exactly those that are $1 \pmod{8}$.  This follows from the standard fact that $(\mathbb{Z}/2^k\mathbb{Z})^\times \cong Z_2\times Z_{2^{k-2}}$, that all squares are $1 \pmod{8}$, and that there are exactly $2^{k-3}$ elements in the latter, and the same number of squares in the former.

The remaining squares in $\mathbb{Z}/2^n\mathbb{Z}$ are all divisible by $4$, so we can work inductively.  If $F(k) = \sum_{n=0}^{2^k-1} f(n)$ ($k\geq 3$), then: $$F(k) - 4F(k-2) = \sum_{n\equiv 1\pmod{8}} n = \sum_{j=0}^{2^{k-3}-1} (8j+1) = 4\cdot 2^{k-3}(2^{k-3}-1) + 2^{k-3}$$ $$=2^{2k-4} - 2^{k-1} + 2^{k-3}$$

Since $F(2) = 1$, we have $F(12) = 4^5 + \sum_{j=2}^6 4^{6-j}(2^{4j-4} - 2^{2j-1} + 2^{2j-3}) = 1390080$.

Taken modulo $2^{12}$, this gives us $1536$.

Comment: I really like your algebraic solution, but unfortunately this is not correct. The answer given is 1536.

Comment: @BohanLu Ah, I just forgot to reduce mod $2^{12}$.